# Inverse of tangent map

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $Tf$ be the tangent map of a one to one map $f$ and let $g$ be the function:  $$g(x,v)=(f(x),Tf(x).v)$$
$g$ is one-to-one, but what is the expression of its inverse ?

Thanks !

Comment: You have to be a bit more careful about what $f$ is, I think. You can be injective without being invertible. Even if the derivative is injective at each point, what if the dimensions don't match up? You could restrict the target of $f$, but then you have to think about the appropriate manifold structure to put on the image. An example that usually helps is immersing the open interval $(0, 1)$ in the plane as a "figure eight".

Comment: [Unless one-to-one means bijective.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if $f$ is one-to-one then $Tf$ is not necessarily one-to-one.

For example, if $f(x) = x^3$, then
$$Tf(x, v) = (x^3, 3x^2v),$$
which is certainly not one-to-one.

However, if $Df_p$ is one-to-one for all $p$ and $f$ is one-to-one, we can easily define the inverse:
$$(Tf)^{-1}(y, w) = (f^{-1}(y), (Df_{f^{-1}(y)})^{-1}(w)).$$

One-to-one maps $f$ such that $Df_p$ is injective for all $p$ are called **injective immersions**.